# Block application until user data has been loaded

Tags: javascript, angular, xmlhttprequest, jwt

I'm writing an angular2 application. To authenticate the user, I'm storing a token in the local storage. This tokens contains only a bit of information to identify the user, no further information like user roles and so on. What Now I want to archive this:

When the user (re)loads the page (any route) and there is a token stored, then I want to make a XHR to retrieve the user data. I want the application (router?) to wait until the server has sent the data.

My question is: Where should I place this request and how do I block the application until the server has responded?

Comment: https://auth0.com/blog/creating-your-first-real-world-angular-2-app-from-authentication-to-calling-an-api-and-everything-in-between/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use guards in order to protect specific routes of your application.
the guards have CanActivate method which can perform async operation and decide if the user can navigate to the route.

More details about the implementation can be found [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#can-activate-guard) and [here](http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/07/18/guards-in-angular-2.html).

The main idea is create children routes for you application which all protected by 'AuthGuard' which retrieves the user info with the stored cookie and verifies that the user is logged in.

Also you can refer the code snippet below:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate, Router, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot } from '@angular/router';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
   constructor(private router: Router, private userDataService: UserDataService ) {}

   canActivate(next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {


       return Observable.fromPromise(this.userDataService.isUserAuthenticated()).map((isUserAuthenticated: boolean) => {
            return true;
       }).catch( error => {
            this.router.navigate(['/login']);
            return Observable.of(false);
       });
   };
}
```

Here the isUserAuthenticated method returns a promise which will be resolved/rejected when we got the response from the server with the user details

Comment: I already have such an auth guard, but right now it returns a boolean (is there a valid token or not), not a promise. And I can load the user data here, of course. Thank you!